# jOOQ inbuilt method generates uncertain query which has fully qualified "column" name

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I am working on Spring Boot and connecting to PostgreSQL and using jOOQ.

jOOQ's inbuilt "update" method of DSLContext generating uncertain query which has fully qualified column name. It throws BadSqlGrammerException when it runs on PostgreSQL.

**Inbuilt method used**:

```
dslContext.update(Tables.TEST).set(row(Tables.TEST.COLUMN1, Tables.TEST.COLUMN2),
                row(col1, col2))
                .where(Tables.TEST.COLUMN3.eq(col3))
                .execute();
```

**Generated query**:

```
update "abc"."test" set "abc"."test"."column1" = ?, "abc"."test"."column2" = ? where "abc"."test"."column3" = ?;
```

**Exception Occurred**:

```
"message": "Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [update \"abc\".\"test\" set \"abc\".\"test\".\"column1\" = ?, \"abc\".\"test\".\"column2\" = ? where \"abc\".\"test\".\"column3\" = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"abc\" of relation \"test\" does not exist\n Position: 30]",
```

**Stack Trace**:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column \"abc\" of relation \"test\" does not exist
 Position: 30
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:214)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:458)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:953)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:375)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:119)
    at *package & class names* java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

***This scenario has occurred only once and I am unable to recreate this issue***

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If that's happening, then you're not using the correct `SQLDialect`. The stack trace (which you omitted) should indicate what `SQLDialect` has been used in your case.

Comment: Updated the question with Stack Trace

Comment: Do you mean to include "spring.jooq.sql-dialect = Postgres" in the application property file 
 and this issue would not repeat?

Comment: @BrajeshJha: OK it looks like the stack trace isn't the one from jOOQ's `DataAccessException` which would contain the `SQLDialect`. Anyway, you can check this easily. Just log `dslContext.dialect()` to see what dialect you configured jOOQ with. I can't tell you why you got the misconfiguration, there can be various reasons, but that's what happened here.

Comment: Postgres is the dialect configured. I have logged this exactly at the point where update method generated uncertain query:

logger.info("SQLDialect Used --> {}",dslContext.dialect());

"message":"SQLDialect Used --> POSTGRES"

Comment: @BrajeshJha: But then, maybe you're not showing the *exact* code that you're executing?

Comment: Right, but its exactly the same code, just I have changed schema, table and column names to some dummy names.

Comment: Well, you can use a debugger and step through the code to see what dialect is being used to generate your SQL and why. If you think there's a bug, you can report one here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose, but be sure to create an example that helps reproduce this (e.g. by using this template: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve)

Comment: Sure, will do that. I tried several times, was unable to reproduce the issue, but will create an exactly same example with which the issue was generated. Thanks for your help, Lukas.